# How to Work with filenames containing emojis in a Windows Command Prompt or batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am running a Windows batch script. When it encounters a filename that contains an emoji the script balks.

```
can't open input file `??.mp3': Invalid argument
```

I have tried setting the code page to Unicode, but it doesn't help.

```
chcp 65001
```

If I execute the `dir` command in a cmd.exe window, the emoji shows as a box. How can I support emojis in a Command Prompt window or batch script?

Comment: So, what is the command you are using, which outputs ```can't open input file `??.mp3': Invalid argument```? and how are you invoking it, both in a Command Prompt window, and from a batch script?

Comment: Use a terminal with full Unicode support like Windows Terminal instead. `cmd` uses `conhost.exe` as the terminal by default, and conhost doesn't support characters outside the BMP like most of the emojis

Comment: But you can use old naming DOS-style 8.3. For `dir` command use `/x` option.

Comment: If Unicode isn't supported by my program or the DOS window, how can I strip or replace the emojis before running the script?

Comment: You can use any Windows automation technology: WSH or Powershell. For doughnut example: `Get-ChildItem -Path c:\music\*.mp3 -Recurse | where{$_.name -like '*'+[char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F369)+'*'}|rename-item -newname {$_.name -replace [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F369)," "}`. Where 0x1f369 is unicode number of  P.S. not good code - just simple example